# Is data driven identification in a simultaneous equation model possible?

Tags: regression, correlation, modeling, identifiability

Suppose I have to estimate 3 models:

$y_1 = y_2\beta_1 + y_3\beta_2 + X\beta_3 + u_1$

$y_2 = y_1\alpha_1 + y_3\alpha_2 + X\alpha_3 + u_2$

$y_3 = y_1\gamma_1 + y_2\gamma_2 + X\gamma_3 + u_3$

I account for the endogeneity of $y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$ with a approach which creates a additional variable which allows me to not exlude any other regressors.

Suppose these additional regressors are $c_1$ for $y_1$, $c_2$ for $y_2$ and $c_3$ for $y_3$. Now the models will be:

$y_1 = y_2\beta_1 + y_3\beta_2 + X\beta_3 + c_2\beta_4 + c_3\beta_5 + u_1$

$y_2 = y_1\alpha_1 + y_3\alpha_2 + X\alpha_3 + c_1\alpha_4 + c_3\alpha_5 + u_2$

$y_3 = y_1\gamma_1 + y_2\gamma_2 + X\gamma_3 + c_1\gamma_4 + c_2\gamma_5 + u_2$

Given that the influence of the $c_i$ in each equation is significant, identification is achieved. The reason is that in each equation one $c_i$ is missing (for example $c_1$ in the $y_1$ equation).

It turns out that I cannot leave $c_1$ out of the equation regarding $y_1$ (same for all the other equations). If I would, the model would be seriously biased.

My questions are: When I estimate the full model, i.e., all $c_i$ are included in every equation and some of the regressors contained in $X$ are not signficant and these regressors are all different for each equation, is identification achieved?

I would say yes. But this approach does only achieve identification through the insignificance of a regressor. I'm not quite sure if this is the right angle to it.